# Which version of Google.Protobuf is good for .netframework 4.0?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

When I install version from 3.0.0 to 3.5.1, error message as below:

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Google.Protobuf 3.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Protobuf -Version 3.5.1 -Project HDExamine
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Then I refer to nuget package site, its dependencies include NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1), after I installed NETStandard.Library 2.0.1 successfully, but the err message is still the same.

My application is based on .net framework 4.0, want to know which version of Google.Protobuf I can use, very appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the official Google packages target .NET 4.5 (and .NET Standard) - and has **never** targeted anything lower than .NET 4.5. There *could* be a technical reason for this, but it *could* be simply testing, convenience, etc. So one option is to simply clone it locally and try changing the target framework: see what breaks.

Alternatively, if you're not tied to that implementation: protobuf-net targets *all* the versions (well, not quite - I finally dropped .NET 1.1). The API works differently, but it should still have what you need, including .proto to C# codegen (https://protogen.marcgravell.com is the easiest way to do that; there's also a download on the page for the command-line tool, which has more features).

Comment: Thanks Marc, I use https://protogen.marcgravell.com to generate c# code, however I use Visual Studio 2013 which cannot build generated code successfully, I think the code is using features of c# 6 (e.g. => in the code). How can I fix the code to work with vs 2013? thanks.

Comment: @JamesHao the tool includes the ability to generate down-level c#. I'm not at a PC right now, but the command-line option is `+langver=...` (there are examples in --help). It can also be specified via custom attributes in the .proto file. So: if you are going to need it more than just once: worth getting the tool to do it for you.